# Based on two field input of a form need to generate choices for another field dynamically on Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

```
on _create_mywork_help.html
     *******************************
     
     function generate_daily_time_list() {
    var start_time = document.getElementById("id_start_time").value;
    var interval = Number(document.getElementById("id_interval").value);
    var  daily = document.getElementById("id_daily");
    //document.getElementById("id_daily").value =  document.getElementById("id_daily").defaultValue;
    document.getElementById("id_daily").innerHTML = "";
    console.log(start_time);
    console.log(interval);
    console.log(daily);

    const stime = String(start_time).split(" ");
    const hm = stime[0].split(":");
    console.log(hm[0]);
    console.log(hm[1]);
    var hr = Number(hm[0]);
    var mins = String(hm[1]);
    var pre = 0;
    while (hr > 0){
        pre = hr;
        hr = hr - interval;
    }
    console.log(mins);
    console.log('Deba');
    var i = pre;
    while (i < 24){
        var option= document.createElement("option");
        dtime = String(i).padStart(2, '0')+':'+mins;
        //dtime_v = 'x'+String(i).padStart(2, '0')+mins;
        console.log(dtime)
        i = i+interval;
        option.value= dtime;
        option.text= dtime;
        daily.add(option);
    }
}

     
     
     class myworkAction(workflows.Action):
         start_time = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Start Time"), required=False)

         interval = forms.CharField(label=_("Hourly"),
                                 required=False,
                                 initial=24,
                                 validators=[validate_scheduler_interval],
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(
                                     attrs={'placeholder': "Repeat interval must be in numbers only (Ex: 1 or 2)...",
                                            'onkeyup': " $('#id_interval').val(document.getElementById('id_interval').value)",
                                            'onchange': "generate_daily_time_list()"}))
         
          daily = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label=_("Daily"), required=False)
    
          class Meta:
        name = _("mywork")
        help_text_template = ("project/workloads/"
                              "_create_mywork_help.html")

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myworkAction, self).__init__(request,
                                        *args, **kwargs)
        start_time_list = populate_time_list()
        self.fields['start_time'].choices = start_time_list
```

I want to take input 12:15 PM start time and interval e.g. 2

It should generate choices for "daily" filed as  e.g. like 14:15 , 16:15

and it is generating, but when i select and submitting it is giving error :

Select a valid choice. 14:15 is not one of the available choices.
bcz self.fields['daily'].choices is blank [], not getting updated on python layer, however on UI showing all list.

It should update choice list, but not updating.